# Prioritize iPhone when connecting August EP650 Bluetooth headphones?

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth, headphones

Both my iPhone (6S+) and iPad (Pro 9.7") have been paired with my Bluetooth headphones (August EP650). When I power on my headphones, they **always** connect to the iPad... despite last being connected to the iPhone.

The iPhone is my primary listening device, so it becomes quite annoying to constantly connect the headphones manually.

How can I prioritize the connection to my iPhone?

To be clear, I still use the headphones on the iPad... just not as often… so I'd rather not *forget* the headphones on the iPad or disable Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These model headphones support *Multipoint* functionality, meaning you can connect them to two devices at the same time.

**Using multipoint**

The procedure for using these headphones in multipoint mode is as follows:

1. Hold the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> buttons to put the EP650 into pairing 
   mode
2. Press the <kbd>▶</kbd> button to start multi-point pairing
3. Pair your headphones to your iPhone
4. Switch your headphones off
5. Press and **hold** the <kbd>▶</kbd> button until your headphones reenter pairing mode
6. Pair your headphones to your iPad
7. Use the Bluetooth menu on your iPhone to reconnect to your headphones

Now you can switch between your iPhone and iPad by pausing the music on the 
currently connected device to play music on the second device. In this way, both devices can be connected simultaneously.

**NOTES:**

- Switching devices can take up to 10 seconds.
- When receiving a call on the iPhone, your headphones will automatically pause and resume once the call is finished, even if you were using the iPad at the time.

Comment: Yeah. That totally did the trick! Thanks. Basically now things are just working in reverse: the iPhone connects first, then I can connect the iPad manually, and then they're both connected. Not exactly sure what the multiport accomplished though… I think that's what was happening before, but the iPad was the device that connected automatically. So… did pairing the iPhone first (before the iPad) put it in the priority spot? Is that the real trick here?

Comment: Yes, the primary source is paired first (at least that's how it's _supposed_ to work), but sometimes Bluetooth has a mind of its own. :) What _multipoint_ does is it allows both devices to be connected at the same time rather than having to disconnect one before reconnecting the other. So, in your case, the idea was to just set things up so both are connected simultaneously and if for whatever reason your iPad connected first you could just pause it and then start playing music on your iPhone to automatically switch over to that without having to do anything else (except maybe wait 10secs).